# DataTables warning: table id=datatable - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0

Tags: codeigniter, datatable

can someone tell me what's wrong with my code? been stuck here for hours... it always says that "DataTables warning: table id=datatable - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0."

here's my code:

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th>Name</th>
                <th></th> 
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message'); ?>
            <?php $offset = $this->uri->segment(3, 0) + 1; ?>
            <?php foreach ($query->result() as $row): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row->manufacturer_name; ?></td>


                    <?php echo "<form method='post' action='asset_management/updateForm'>";?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="manufacturer_id" value="<?php echo $row->manufacturer_id;?>"/>
                    <?php echo form_open('asset_management/updateForm');
                        echo form_submit('p_submit', 'Update', "class='btn btn-warning btn-xs'"); ?>
                        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
                    </form>

                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="javascript:deleteConfirm('<?php echo site_url('asset_management/deletemanu/' . $row->manufacturer_id); ?>');" deleteConfirm href="#">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></th>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: check the console you'll get php error/javascript share here. You have 2 `TH` but `TD`'s are less

Comment: thank you very much sir @Sundar! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no. of table heading may not matches with no. of td in the table.

It shows the mentioned error.

visit https://www.datatables.net/